# Creating text out of SVG <path>'s

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm wondering if theres any tools to create text out of SVG `<path>` elements. I found this codepen I really like and would like to be able to use it with my own text.

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I tried looking on google and couldn't find anything

https://codepen.io/robin-dela/pen/KKPYoBq

Comment: Inkscape and Illustrator can do that. I don't think you actually need a tool, though. SVG has a `<text>` element.

Comment: The codepen you're showing does not create text out of paths, so it's rather unclear what you're actually asking help with. The codepen has a SVG file with paths, acting as a graphics mask, and JS that effects a "liquid" coloring underneath that mask.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans sorry I guess I misunderstood, my question is: How can I add my own text into the animation? I want to be able to have that effect on the word Luxe Lashes

Comment: By using any vector graphics package or text outline vectoring tool that lets you write text (illustrator, inkscape, or even opentype.js or the like) and then saving or exporting that as (web-optimized) SVG. Then copy-pasting the markup in that file.

Comment: https://codepen.io/_-0-_/pen/GRjLaVw

Comment: @Kaiido wow!! thanks so much! thats perfect, if you post that as an answer ill be glad to accept :)

Comment: That doesn't answer the current question though, that just gives you what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can there are a lot of tools to help you in that by entering the text and it will convert it to SVG path for example [Google font to SVG path](https://danmarshall.github.io/google-font-to-svg-path/) tool.

every time you want to change the text just use [Google font to SVG path](https://danmarshall.github.io/google-font-to-svg-path/) to generate your word SVG path and put it into your code.

here is an example based on your Codepen:

```js
var vertex = `
        attribute vec2 uv;
        attribute vec2 position;
        varying vec2 vUv;
        void main() {
                vUv = uv;
                gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);
        }
`;
var fragment = `
        precision highp float;
        precision highp int;
        uniform sampler2D tWater;
        uniform sampler2D tFlow;
        uniform float uTime;
        varying vec2 vUv;
        uniform vec4 res;
        uniform vec2 img;

        vec2 centeredAspectRatio(vec2 uvs, vec2 factor){
                return uvs * factor - factor /2. + 0.5;
        }

        void main() {

            // R and G values are velocity in the x and y direction
            // B value is the velocity length
            vec3 flow = texture2D(tFlow, vUv).rgb;

            vec2 uv = .5 * gl_FragCoord.xy / res.xy ;

            // vec2 uv = .5 * gl_FragCoord.xy / res.xy ;
            vec2 myUV = (uv - vec2(0.5))*res.zw + vec2(0.5);
            myUV -= flow.xy * (0.15 * 1.2);

            vec2 myUV2 = (uv - vec2(0.5))*res.zw + vec2(0.5);
            myUV2 -= flow.xy * (0.125 * 1.2);

            vec2 myUV3 = (uv - vec2(0.5))*res.zw + vec2(0.5);
            myUV3 -= flow.xy * (0.10 * 1.4);

            vec3 tex = texture2D(tWater, myUV).rgb;
            vec3 tex2 = texture2D(tWater, myUV2).rgb;
            vec3 tex3 = texture2D(tWater, myUV3).rgb;

            gl_FragColor = vec4(tex.r, tex2.g, tex3.b, 1.0);
        }
`;
{
  var _size = [2048, 1638];
  var renderer = new ogl.Renderer({ dpr: 2 });
  var gl = renderer.gl;
  document.body.appendChild(gl.canvas);

  // Variable inputs to control flowmap
  var aspect = 1;
  var mouse = new ogl.Vec2(-1);
  var velocity = new ogl.Vec2();
  function resize() {
    gl.canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 2.0;
    gl.canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 2.0;
    gl.canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth + "px";
    gl.canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";

    var a1, a2;
    var imageAspect = _size[1] / _size[0];
    if (window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth < imageAspect) {
      a1 = 1;
      a2 = window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth / imageAspect;
    } else {
      a1 = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight * imageAspect;
      a2 = 1;
    }
    mesh.program.uniforms.res.value = new ogl.Vec4(
    window.innerWidth,
    window.innerHeight,
    a1,
    a2);


    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  }
  var flowmap = new ogl.Flowmap(gl, {
    falloff: 0.3,
    dissipation: 0.92,
    alpha: 0.5 });

  // Triangle that includes -1 to 1 range for 'position', and 0 to 1 range for 'uv'.
  var geometry = new ogl.Geometry(gl, {
    position: {
      size: 2,
      data: new Float32Array([-1, -1, 3, -1, -1, 3]) },

    uv: { size: 2, data: new Float32Array([0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2]) } });

  var texture = new ogl.Texture(gl, {
    minFilter: gl.LINEAR,
    magFilter: gl.LINEAR });

  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = () => texture.image = img;
  img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
  img.src = "https://robindelaporte.fr/codepen/bg3.jpg";

  var a1, a2;
  var imageAspect = _size[1] / _size[0];
  if (window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth < imageAspect) {
    a1 = 1;
    a2 = window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth / imageAspect;
  } else {
    a1 = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight * imageAspect;
    a2 = 1;
  }

  var program = new ogl.Program(gl, {
    vertex,
    fragment,
    uniforms: {
      uTime: { value: 0 },
      tWater: { value: texture },
      res: {
        value: new ogl.Vec4(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, a1, a2) },

      img: { value: new ogl.Vec2(_size[1], _size[0]) },
      // Note that the uniform is applied without using an object and value property
      // This is because the class alternates this texture between two render targets
      // and updates the value property after each render.
      tFlow: flowmap.uniform } });


  var mesh = new ogl.Mesh(gl, { geometry, program });

  window.addEventListener("resize", resize, false);
  resize();

  // Create handlers to get mouse position and velocity
  var isTouchCapable = ("ontouchstart" in window);
  if (isTouchCapable) {
    window.addEventListener("touchstart", updateMouse, false);
    window.addEventListener("touchmove", updateMouse, { passive: false });
  } else {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", updateMouse, false);
  }
  var lastTime;
  var lastMouse = new ogl.Vec2();
  function updateMouse(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.changedTouches && e.changedTouches.length) {
      e.x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
      e.y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
    }
    if (e.x === undefined) {
      e.x = e.pageX;
      e.y = e.pageY;
    }
    // Get mouse value in 0 to 1 range, with y flipped
    mouse.set(e.x / gl.renderer.width, 1.0 - e.y / gl.renderer.height);
    // Calculate velocity
    if (!lastTime) {
      // First frame
      lastTime = performance.now();
      lastMouse.set(e.x, e.y);
    }

    var deltaX = e.x - lastMouse.x;
    var deltaY = e.y - lastMouse.y;

    lastMouse.set(e.x, e.y);

    var time = performance.now();

    // Avoid dividing by 0
    var delta = Math.max(10.4, time - lastTime);
    lastTime = time;
    velocity.x = deltaX / delta;
    velocity.y = deltaY / delta;
    // Flag update to prevent hanging velocity values when not moving
    velocity.needsUpdate = true;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
  function update(t) {
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
    // Reset velocity when mouse not moving
    if (!velocity.needsUpdate) {
      mouse.set(-1);
      velocity.set(0);
    }
    velocity.needsUpdate = false;
    // Update flowmap inputs
    flowmap.aspect = aspect;
    flowmap.mouse.copy(mouse);
    // Ease velocity input, slower when fading out
    flowmap.velocity.lerp(velocity, velocity.len ? 0.15 : 0.1);
    flowmap.update();
    program.uniforms.uTime.value = t * 0.01;
    renderer.render({ scene: mesh });
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.mask {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: white;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  /* display: none; */
}

svg {
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://robindelaporte.fr/codepen/bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div class="mask">

        <svg id="Layer_1" width="500.25" height="300.401" viewBox="0 0 124.25 35.401" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g id="svgGroup" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="9pt" stroke="#000" stroke-width="0.25mm" fill="" ><path class="st0" d="M 0.287 14.019 A 28.282 28.282 0 0 0 0 18.15 A 32.323 32.323 0 0 0 0.167 21.511 Q 0.796 27.521 3.8 31 Q 7.6 35.4 14.525 35.4 Q 21.45 35.4 25.875 30.575 Q 30.3 25.75 30.3 16.75 Q 30.3 12.5 29.225 9.3 Q 28.579 7.375 27.769 5.984 A 10.057 10.057 0 0 0 26.625 4.375 Q 25.1 2.65 22.95 1.625 A 22.239 22.239 0 0 0 22.015 1.205 Q 21.254 0.884 20.556 0.663 A 11.47 11.47 0 0 0 19.1 0.3 Q 17.4 0 15.55 0 A 14.963 14.963 0 0 0 10.221 0.967 A 17.387 17.387 0 0 0 5.45 3.75 A 10.119 10.119 0 0 0 4.91 4.213 Q 3.765 5.263 2.846 6.738 A 17.31 17.31 0 0 0 1.5 9.425 A 17.43 17.43 0 0 0 1.384 9.722 Q 0.631 11.696 0.287 14.019 Z M 15.1 30.7 Q 24.05 30.7 24.05 17.55 A 28.133 28.133 0 0 0 23.703 12.915 Q 22.273 4.4 14.95 4.4 A 9.734 9.734 0 0 0 12.536 4.685 A 7.198 7.198 0 0 0 9.675 6.125 Q 7.6 7.85 6.8 10.425 Q 6 13 6 16.4 A 33.631 33.631 0 0 0 6.32 21.26 Q 7.706 30.7 15.1 30.7 Z" id="0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><path class="st0" d="M 33.7 13.4 L 33.7 10.8 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 33.737 10.503 Q 33.833 10.17 34.172 10.082 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 34.45 10.05 L 41.3 10.05 A 0.819 0.819 0 0 1 41.618 10.108 Q 41.978 10.258 42.05 10.8 L 42.45 13.7 A 8.722 8.722 0 0 1 45.429 10.703 Q 47.085 9.726 49.233 9.542 A 11.966 11.966 0 0 1 50.25 9.5 A 9.347 9.347 0 0 1 52.894 9.848 Q 55.914 10.738 57.1 13.9 A 9.588 9.588 0 0 1 59.583 11.134 Q 61.533 9.704 64.18 9.526 A 11.433 11.433 0 0 1 64.95 9.5 A 10.083 10.083 0 0 1 68.146 9.963 Q 72.659 11.47 72.7 17.882 A 18.445 18.445 0 0 1 72.7 18 L 72.7 30.85 L 75.55 30.85 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 75.847 30.887 Q 76.18 30.983 76.268 31.322 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 76.3 31.6 L 76.3 34.05 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 76.263 34.347 Q 76.168 34.68 75.828 34.768 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 75.55 34.8 L 64.55 34.8 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 64.253 34.763 Q 63.921 34.668 63.832 34.328 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 63.8 34.05 L 63.8 31.6 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 63.837 31.303 Q 63.933 30.97 64.272 30.882 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 64.55 30.85 L 67.1 30.85 L 67.1 20.5 A 19.73 19.73 0 0 0 67.04 18.905 Q 66.916 17.374 66.531 16.396 A 4.228 4.228 0 0 0 66.3 15.9 A 2.552 2.552 0 0 0 64.913 14.738 Q 64.155 14.45 63.075 14.45 A 7.356 7.356 0 0 0 61.458 14.618 Q 60.129 14.917 59.2 15.75 A 4.704 4.704 0 0 0 58.275 16.857 A 3.756 3.756 0 0 0 57.75 18.8 L 57.75 30.85 L 60.15 30.85 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 60.447 30.887 Q 60.78 30.983 60.868 31.322 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 60.9 31.6 L 60.9 34.05 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 60.863 34.347 Q 60.768 34.68 60.428 34.768 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 60.15 34.8 L 49.9 34.8 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 49.603 34.763 Q 49.271 34.668 49.182 34.328 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 49.15 34.05 L 49.15 31.6 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 49.187 31.303 Q 49.283 30.97 49.622 30.882 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 49.9 30.85 L 52.15 30.85 L 52.15 20.5 A 19.73 19.73 0 0 0 52.09 18.905 Q 51.966 17.374 51.581 16.396 A 4.228 4.228 0 0 0 51.35 15.9 A 2.534 2.534 0 0 0 50.001 14.758 Q 49.535 14.575 48.943 14.501 A 6.978 6.978 0 0 0 48.075 14.45 A 6.698 6.698 0 0 0 46.432 14.641 A 4.652 4.652 0 0 0 44.175 15.925 A 5.128 5.128 0 0 0 43.106 17.519 A 4.719 4.719 0 0 0 42.75 19.35 L 42.75 30.85 L 45.8 30.85 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 46.097 30.887 Q 46.43 30.983 46.518 31.322 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 46.55 31.6 L 46.55 34.05 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 46.513 34.347 Q 46.418 34.68 46.078 34.768 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 45.8 34.8 L 34.5 34.8 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 34.203 34.763 Q 33.871 34.668 33.782 34.328 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 33.75 34.05 L 33.75 31.6 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 33.787 31.303 Q 33.883 30.97 34.222 30.882 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 34.5 30.85 L 37.15 30.85 L 37.15 14.15 L 34.45 14.15 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 34.153 14.113 Q 33.821 14.018 33.732 13.678 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 33.7 13.4 Z" id="1" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><path class="st0" d="M 93.5 19.95 L 93.5 18.2 A 9.647 9.647 0 0 0 93.39 16.682 Q 93.268 15.915 93.008 15.33 A 2.968 2.968 0 0 0 91.5 13.75 A 4.051 4.051 0 0 0 90.823 13.539 Q 90.105 13.377 89.09 13.354 A 15.117 15.117 0 0 0 88.75 13.35 A 5.387 5.387 0 0 0 87.177 13.563 Q 85.452 14.089 84.826 15.917 A 5.734 5.734 0 0 0 84.65 16.55 A 1.491 1.491 0 0 1 84.559 16.851 Q 84.37 17.287 83.927 17.3 A 0.936 0.936 0 0 1 83.9 17.3 L 80.7 17.3 Q 79.9 17.3 80 16.55 A 7.966 7.966 0 0 1 80.439 14.271 A 5.867 5.867 0 0 1 82.95 11.2 A 10.731 10.731 0 0 1 86.13 9.912 Q 87.507 9.584 89.115 9.517 A 20.158 20.158 0 0 1 89.95 9.5 A 14.16 14.16 0 0 1 93.383 9.879 Q 97.836 10.995 98.695 15.405 A 12.019 12.019 0 0 1 98.9 17.7 L 98.9 30.85 L 101.05 30.85 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 101.347 30.887 Q 101.68 30.983 101.768 31.322 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 101.8 31.6 L 101.8 34.05 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 101.763 34.347 Q 101.668 34.68 101.328 34.768 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 101.05 34.8 L 95.15 34.8 A 0.819 0.819 0 0 1 94.832 34.742 Q 94.472 34.592 94.4 34.05 L 94.05 31.75 A 8.78 8.78 0 0 1 87.642 35.327 A 12.938 12.938 0 0 1 86.25 35.4 A 10.061 10.061 0 0 1 83.832 35.124 A 7.408 7.408 0 0 1 80.95 33.725 A 5.2 5.2 0 0 1 79.256 31.211 Q 78.964 30.324 78.882 29.235 A 11.781 11.781 0 0 1 78.85 28.35 Q 78.85 23.553 82.812 21.74 A 8.786 8.786 0 0 1 82.9 21.7 A 17.364 17.364 0 0 1 86.701 20.474 Q 88.465 20.11 90.481 20.017 A 29.489 29.489 0 0 1 90.9 20 Q 91.628 20 92.765 19.971 A 162.373 162.373 0 0 0 93.5 19.95 Z M 93.6 27.25 L 93.6 23.4 A 81.655 81.655 0 0 0 91.93 23.416 Q 88.594 23.484 87.7 23.85 A 25.7 25.7 0 0 0 86.663 24.3 A 18.714 18.714 0 0 0 85.75 24.75 Q 84.15 25.6 84.15 27.85 A 4.287 4.287 0 0 0 84.374 29.298 Q 85.054 31.195 87.791 31.295 A 8.517 8.517 0 0 0 88.1 31.3 A 8.903 8.903 0 0 0 89.683 31.168 Q 90.569 31.008 91.273 30.653 A 4.486 4.486 0 0 0 92.15 30.075 A 4.729 4.729 0 0 0 92.976 29.189 A 3.301 3.301 0 0 0 93.6 27.25 Z" id="2" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><path  class="st0" d="M 124.25 10.8 L 124.25 17.55 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 124.213 17.847 Q 124.118 18.18 123.778 18.268 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 123.5 18.3 L 120.25 18.3 A 1.082 1.082 0 0 1 119.976 18.269 Q 119.52 18.149 119.549 17.573 A 1.474 1.474 0 0 1 119.55 17.55 L 119.75 14.65 Q 119.502 14.6 118.91 14.6 A 13.297 13.297 0 0 0 118.9 14.6 A 4.593 4.593 0 0 0 115.438 16.087 A 6.025 6.025 0 0 0 115.1 16.475 A 6.486 6.486 0 0 0 113.914 18.887 Q 113.661 19.831 113.612 20.948 A 12.535 12.535 0 0 0 113.6 21.5 L 113.6 30.85 L 119.1 30.85 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 119.397 30.887 Q 119.73 30.983 119.818 31.322 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 119.85 31.6 L 119.85 34.05 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 119.813 34.347 Q 119.718 34.68 119.378 34.768 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 119.1 34.8 L 105.35 34.8 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 105.053 34.763 Q 104.721 34.668 104.632 34.328 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 104.6 34.05 L 104.6 31.6 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 104.637 31.303 Q 104.733 30.97 105.072 30.882 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 105.35 30.85 L 108 30.85 L 108 14.15 L 105.3 14.15 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 105.003 14.113 Q 104.671 14.018 104.582 13.678 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 104.55 13.4 L 104.55 10.8 A 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 104.587 10.503 Q 104.683 10.17 105.022 10.082 A 1.105 1.105 0 0 1 105.3 10.05 L 111.9 10.05 A 0.966 0.966 0 0 1 112.25 10.109 Q 112.642 10.261 112.75 10.8 L 113.3 14.35 A 8.128 8.128 0 0 1 115.482 11.384 A 9.875 9.875 0 0 1 116.05 10.925 Q 117.95 9.5 120.2 9.5 A 20.41 20.41 0 0 1 121.444 9.535 Q 122.636 9.608 123.432 9.833 A 4.92 4.92 0 0 1 123.65 9.9 Q 124.123 10.058 124.223 10.525 A 1.309 1.309 0 0 1 124.25 10.8 Z" id="3" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/></g>   <style type="text/css">
            .st0 {
              fill-rule: evenodd;
              clip-rule: evenodd;
            }
          </style>
        </svg>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to write text in Svg Like this if you don't want to use path.

```
  <svg height="90" width="200">
  <text x="10" y="20" style="fill:red;">Several lines:
    <tspan x="10" y="45">First line.</tspan>
    <tspan x="10" y="70">Second line.</tspan>
  </text
    </svg>
```